# filter unknown string from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently working with database which is generated directly from machine instruments.(PI Data)
I am trying to remove information from the database which is mainly related to communication error.
For example

```
df_ex = pd.DataFrame({'Ambient': [20.11112, 'Bad',200.22222],
                  'Humidity': [50.47585, 89.14251,'Bad Input'],
                  'Compressor Temp': [50.47585, 89.14251,72.89657],
                  'Bearing Temp': ['Scan off', 74.45551, 52.2227]})
```

`df_ex`:

```
     Ambient   Humidity  Compressor Temp Bearing Temp
0   20.11112   50.47585         50.47585     Scan off
1        Bad   89.14251         89.14251     74.45551
2  200.22222  Bad Input         72.89657      52.2227
```

Errors received with df is filtered out by using below code.

```
df_ex.replace(['Bad','Bad Input','Scan Off'],np.nan, inplace=True)
df_ex.replace(" ", np.nan, inplace=True)
df_ex.dropna(inplace = True)
```

I am trying to figure out way on how can I remove errors "Bad", "Bad Input" etc from dataframe by filtering out unknown error. I am filtering errors manually most of the time from excel file.

Due to huge size of data base trying unique value also doesn't help in filtering as there are many unique decimal values.

I used this code to find unique values to find error in the dataframe

```
df_ex['Ambient'].unique()
```

Errors are changing time to time depending on network communication failure (Unknown error). So instead of "Bad" it may have "Bad Data" which I need to remove manually. If I fail to find out correct name of error my code doesn't run.

Can some one help on this?

Thank you for your time.

I tried `out = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors = 'coerce')` which removed errors but changed Date time in to nan.
[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: So, to make sure, your error-messages are in `df_ex["Ambient"]` or..? I.e how do you know if a message is an unknown error?

Comment: Do bad inputs come always as a string?

Comment: @ CutePoison  Error is in form of string (eg "Failure", "Communication Loss") rest all data is float.

Comment: @ John Giorgio Yes it is always a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you have a dataframe with numerical data and sometimes string values which denote incorrect data.

You could convert [`to numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors="coerce"` to force invalid data to NaN:

```
out = df_ex.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

output:

```
     Ambient  Humidity  Compressor Temp  Bearing Temp
0   20.11112  50.47585         50.47585           NaN
1        NaN  89.14251         89.14251      74.45551
2  200.22222       NaN         72.89657      52.22270
```

Comment: Yes this is working fine for me. The only problem is date time is changing to nan. I used df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE']) to convert it but it shows Date as int. do you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: Can you update your example?

Comment: Output I have updated in the main post.

Comment: @DBV then only apply to a subset of your columns: `cols = ['col1', 'col2'] ; df_ex[cols] = df_ex[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')`